# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL - When trying to insert a response json into my mysql

Tags: mysql, json, longtext

Im trying to insert a response object into MySQL Database, but it fails every time.

```
INSERT INTO response(`debug_response`) 
VALUES ('
   {
    "STATUS": {"code": 200}, 
    "REQUEST": {"q": "The ABC Murders", "resource": "/sherlock/stores/search.flipkart.com/redirection-store"}, 
    "RESPONSE": {"payloadId": "ca1ef0cb-26fc-44d3-9455-a7c4d093caa9", 
    "metadata": {}, 
    "redirectionStore": "search.flipkart.com", "isRedirection": false}
   }
');
```

My column `debug_response` is of type **longText**.

This is the error I am getting :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  "REQUEST": {"q": "The ABC Murders", "resource": "/sher' at line 1

Comment: try using NVARCHAR  datatype

Comment: Are you sure that this exact query goes to MySQL? This one looks totally correct. Could you double check please? Especially, the quote characters.

Comment: The query you mentioned should work fine. Have a look :: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee554f/1.

Comment: Why are you not using the MySQL JSON data type?